# How to find all files with double quotes in name on a mac

Tags: macos, finder, search, file

I tried to find all files with double quotes in name in the search field in Finder. When I just put `"` in there, it's not finding any such files.

Also it suggests `Name contains "` in a dropdown, but when I choose it this doesn't work either.

I'd like to know how to find all files with double quotes in their name. I'd like to know this for both Finder and Terminal.

Comment: @Alper yeah this works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the Finder on your Mac searches for files with regular names correctly otherwise:

1. Press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the Finder when in a regular folder. This should bring up the additional search options in addition to the basic search window on the top right.
2. Don't enter anything to the basic search window but choose `Name` and `contains` as additional criteria and enter `"` to the search window for the criteria.

Then all and only the files which have a double quote in their names should come up immediately. Also below is a screenshot from an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be a job for [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware)
It can find many things Finder & Spotlight wont, including your quotes `"`

It doesn't index, so it's always slower than Spotlight, but it can find just about anything, anywhere on your Mac.

[image]